# Meteor forgot password email not sending

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor, mandrill, meteor-accounts

I'm building a meteor based website. And deploy it in ubuntu vps, with nginx and SSL certified.

When creating forgot password mechanism using *forgotPassword* method:

```
Accounts.forgotPassword({email: the_email});
```

I got "*HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway*" message, and it seems come from Meteor websocket. And of course, no email sent.

I use mandrill for sending email, and the configuration more-less like this:

```
smtp = {
        username: 'dummy@email.com',
        password: 'abgfgtyhuyujkQVD1ox1Od7eQ',
        server:   'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
        port: 587   
}

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username)
    + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
```

This config is inside the *server* folder.

I also tried defining the MAIL_URL environment variable with that mandrill setting and still didn't work.

This only happen in deployed version, but runs well in local. The reset password email successfully sent when I test it in local.

Anybody have experienced this problem?

Comment: Hi, Do you got any solution on this, as I am also facing the same issue. Please let me know  what you have done to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same issue!
Try this (on your VPS):

- cd /home/yourProject/bundle/programs/server && npm install
  --production
- npm install bcrypt simplesmtp
- reboot
- cd /home/yourProject/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/
  && rm -rf npm-bcrypt/
- cd /home/yourProject/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/email/node_modules/
  && rm -rf simplesmtp/
- restart your app